# unrecognized selector sent to instance happening on iOS 12 only

Tags: ios, json, objective-c, iphone

I have an odd issue where the following error is occuring only on one device which is iOS 12 versions only.  Why is this happening only on this OS and not others?

**Error**

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
-[NSTaggedPointerString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe4d38ae23d3589b7
```

**JSON**

```
"Name": "A",
        "Teams": [
            {
                "Number": "3",
```

**Code**

```
poolTeam.number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [poolJson objectForKey:@"Name"], [[teamJson objectForKey:@"Number"] stringValue]];
```

Below is the code that converts the response to JSON

```
- (id)parseResponse {

    @try
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        return jsonDict;
    }
    @catch(NSException *ex) {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show how you're creating `poolJson` and `teamJson`.

Comment: I added the code that converts the response to a NSDictionary which I then start reading

Comment: It seems that `[teamJson objectForKey:@"Number"]` is already a `NSString`, and you are calling `stringValue` on it. Why only in iOS12, that's a good question. Are you sure the JSON is the same? Could it be an issue when it's a NSNumber and sometimes a NSString? Since according to your JSON, it's perfectly normal that it's a NSString...

Comment: So I tested the iOS 13 with the json `number` of type string and a integer and both worked fine.  So something is up with iOS 12 and stringValue with an integer.

Comment: On ios 13 works the same: `-[NSTaggedPointerString stringValue]: unrecognized selector` ‍♂️

Comment: Not here, works totally fine

Comment: Can you have a samole reproducing the issue? Because according to the JSON `"Number": "3",`, that's should definitely create that crash....

Comment: I tested with json “3” and 3 and both worked for iOS 13, NOT 12.

Comment: Do you have a full reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs only with iOS 12.x, if you use [ stringValue] on a NSString. Remove the redundant cast to fix.